# Nightly Code Metrics in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to set up an a process that runs over night (every night) to run Visual Studios Code metrics Analysis?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's very possible.  It's called a build server.  TeamCity, CC.Net and TFS (and more) all offer the abiity to run a job each day that compiles your code and does other things like calculating metrics and code analysis, etc.

Comment: Thanks @Richard. I'm not sure how I managed to miss the "Perform Code Analysis" option in my TFS Build Definition. I'll just change my nightly build. Thanks for pointing that one out.

Comment: I've set up my TFS build definition to "Perform Code Analysis", which does exactly what it says and runs Code Analysis, but not Code Metrics. Is there any way to set it up to run Code Metrics?

Comment: Metrics being cyclomatic complexity, etc?  For those you have to customise the build definition.  I'll see if I can dig up a link for you on how to do it (unless someone chimes in with one first)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the feature we both want isn't implemented yet.
Follow this link for more information and for a possible solution: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/ac59eeea-5e9f-4e60-b9df-4ad1fa3985fe